# Sequelize exclude belongs-to-many mapping object

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a way when making a SequelizeJS query on an object, and including a relation which has a belongs-to-many association, to have the included property not return the association mapping object with the result?

i.e.:

```
Users.findAll({include: [{model: Role, as: 'roles'}]})

//yields objects of the following form
user: {
    username: 'test',
    roles: [
        {
           name: 'user',
           UserRoles: {userId: 1, roleId: 1} //<--I do not want this
        }
    ]        
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Found a solution to this in a github comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4074#issuecomment-153054311

gist:

```
Users.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Role, 
            as: 'roles',
            through: {attributes: []} //<-- this line will prevent mapping object from being added
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try specifying the `attributes` property.

So to include fields say a,b,c you add

```
attributes: ['a', 'b','c']
```

To exclude them

```
attributes:{exclude:['a', 'b','c']}
```

So findAll looks like

```
Model.someModel.findAll({
  where: // some condition
  include: // some other model
  attributes: // some fields
})
```

You can also specify attributes within the include clause

Comment: tried your response and it didn't exclude the UserRoles joining object

Comment: for now i just use a map and delete the UserRoles object from the result before sending to the client.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/einUJ.png)

```js
export const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await User.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: Enrollment,
                    as: 'enrollments',
                    attributes:{exclude:['city']}
                }
            ],
            attributes: { exclude: ['password', 'refresh_token',] }
        })
        res.json(succesResponse(users))
    } catch (error) {
        res.json(errorResonse(error))
    }
}
```

im using this way to solve this issue

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).