# How can I fetch data with many to many relationship without junction table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables here. Suppliers and ProductCategory. While I want to fetch data from Suppliers table with the ProductCategory table then it also shows the junction table data also. How can I get rid of this problem?

Controller code

```
exports.getSuppliers = (req, res) => {
    Suppliers.findAll({
        include: [
            { model: ProductCategory, attributes :['categoryName'],}
        ]
    }).then(supplier =>{
        res.send(supplier);
    }).catch();
}
```

Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Suppliers = sequelize.define('Suppliers', {
    sup_Name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    contact_person: DataTypes.STRING,
    contact_person_phone: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Suppliers.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Suppliers.belongsToMany(models.Product_Category, {through: models.Suppliers_has_categories, foreignKey: 'supplier_id'})
  };
  return Suppliers;
};
```

Result

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "sup_Name": "UCC Bangladesh",
        "email": "tripto_ewu@outlook.com",
        "contact_person": "Jafrul Hossain",
        "contact_person_phone": "01713553308",
        "createdAt": "2019-08-31T16:20:33.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-08-31T16:20:33.000Z",
        "Product_Categories": [
            {
                "categoryName": "Casing",
                "Suppliers_has_categories": {
                    "supplier_id": 1,
                    "category_id": 2,
                    "createdAt": "2019-08-31T16:20:33.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-08-31T16:20:33.000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need only this categoryName from the ProductCategory Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to exclude 'Suppliers_has_categories' field by adding `through: { attributes: [] }` like following.

```
Suppliers.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: ProductCategory,
            attributes :['categoryName'],
            through: { attributes: [] } // <= Add this line.
        }
    ]
})
```

I found this solution in a similar question below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093383/4889634